# Access site with domain name without editing hosts file or setting up DNS

Tags: iis

Im setting up multiple sites on IIS 10, using port 80.
This is only in a home env, not accessible from the outside.

I would like all devices to be able to access these sites with domain name,
without editing the hosts file or setting up DNS.

It seems possbible in apache
See here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111006/how-to-access-a-website-through-a-local-area-network-that-localhost-change-to-a

Can it be done in IIS?
Where do I read up on this?

Br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only ways for a computer to know the mapping between a name and an IP address are DNS or local `hosts` files. What you want is not possibile.

---

Updated for completeness.
On Windows systems there are two additional ways to map names to IP addresses: a WINS server and the LMHOSTS.SAM file; these are mostly relics of old times when Windows networking didn't use DNS name resolution, but they still work.
A WINS server needs to be hosted by a Windows Server system, so you'd need a server to run it; I don't really think this would fit your needs.
The LMHOSTS.SAM file works like the HOSTS file, but with a different syntax; it's also located in the same place: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`.

Comment: Thank you Massimo for confirming this.
I can now move on to next idea.

Comment: Incorrect.  Why do people not know these things about windows when they have such a high StackOverflow score. Please review your answers.

Comment: @csharpforevermore I don't think WINS or LMHOSTS would be of any help to someone who doesn't want to make changes to DNS and/or HOSTS; but I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bind to a URL that ends with **localtest.me** and *it will resolve to 127.0.0.1*

As others have commented, this is because there is a public DNS that flags this - and all subdomains - to 127.0.0.1. This is useful since if you have a website you need hosting locally and yet have no access to the hosts file, you can just add this website binding in IIS for your site.

Comment: This is not a Windows quirk; there is an actual public DNS domain called "localtest.me", configured to answer "127.0.0.1" to any request for any subdomain.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it actually gives an option instead of saying "you cannot".

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check site binding and change domain name for each site in binding with port 80  in IIS configuration window.
dDonot forget to put domain names in host file in your computer.

Comment: Thank you hamid, but I wanted to avoid messing with the hosts file.